# Showing DOM elements depending on click

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of categories - within those categories, there are items:

```
Category 1:
   Item 1
   Item 2
   Item 3

Category 2:
   Item 1
   Item 2
   Item 3

 Category 3:
   Item 1
   Item 2
   Item 3
```

I iterate through the categories and items within. As default, I dont want the items showing. The user has to click on the category to show the items. The problem I am having is that when the user clicks any category, it is expanding the items in all categories.

```
<div>
  <ul data-ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <li data-ng-click="ExpandCategory()">{{category.name}}</li>
      <ul data-ng-show="showItems == true" data-ng-repeat="item in category.items">
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      </ul>         
   </ul>                        
 </div>
```

How do I limit it to the category clicked?

```
$scope.ExpandCategory = function (){
   $scope.showItems = true;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: `showItems == true` can simply be `showItems`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<li data-ng-click="ExpandCategory($index)"> ...
    <ul data-ng-show="showItems[$index]" ...
```

and then:

```
$scope.ExpandCategory = function(index) {
    $scope.showItems[index] = true;
}
```

I probably don't have the syntax just right, but you get the idea.

Comment: I have tried a few versions of that and and it doesnt work. I get an error when trying to pass $index into ExpandCategory() on the mark up... TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined